# Google API on Published Electron app: gapi.auth2.ExternallyVisibleError: Invalid cookiePolicy

Tags: reactjs, google-api, electron, google-calendar-api, google-auth-library

I have a React + Electron app using Google API to authenticate and get a list of calendar events.

The API script is being loaded on the `head` of my `index.html` and initialised on my `App.js` like so:

```
// Initializes the API client library and sets up sign-in state listeners.
  initClient() {
    let gapi = window["gapi"];
    let that = this;

    gapi.load("client", start);

    function start() {
      gapi.client
        .init({
          apiKey: GOOGLE_API_KEY,
          clientId: CLIENT_ID,
          discoveryDocs: [
            "https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/calendar/v3/rest"
          ],
          scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly"
        })
        .then(() => {
          gapi.auth2
            .getAuthInstance()
            .isSignedIn.listen(that.updateSigninStatus);

          that.updateSigninStatus(
            gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.get()
          );

          that.setState({
            apiLoaded: true
          });
        });
    }
  }
```

It works completely fine on a local environment, where I have a server running, but once I build my Electron app and run the app "natively", I get the following error: `gapi.auth2.ExternallyVisibleError: Invalid cookiePolicy`

I don't have an advanced understanding of APIs and Servers to figure this out but through research, I found something about the API not working from a "file://" protocol, which is the case on an Electron app.

Thoughts? Ideas?

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Comment: Any updates on this one?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken I ended up having to start a server in the background and make the calls from there. @deathangel908